# how can put the last row with border using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need write the last row with borders. I have tried with:

```
paragraph.setBorderBottom(Borders.BASIC_BLACK_SQUARES);
paragraph.setBorderTop(Borders.BASIC_BLACK_SQUARES);
```

but the result is wrong. Please, could someone help me ?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `paragraph`?  Which part of Apache POI are you working with?  Word? Excel?

Comment: Sorry, my paragraph is a XWPFParagraph. I have a table in a word document, and I want a the result row with a border. Only the last row. Thank you very much